# Can someone explain this line

Tags: java, for-loop, iterator

hello i'm trying ton understand a programm and a line giving me some trouble. Can you explain me the Construction of this line because i have never seen a "For" like that

```
for (Iterator<IBaseVO> itMachine = machinesSelected.iterator(); itMachine.hasNext();) {
            MachineVO mach = (MachineVO) itMachine.next();
            idsMachines.add(mach.getMchId());
        }
```

thanks you

Comment: What is the trouble it is giving to you? ;)

Comment: i don't understant why it have to ";" in the first line

Comment: clearly duplicate of that thans ks you i close

Comment: `for (initialize itMachine; the condition itMachine.hasNext(); no incremental, just loop) {...}`

Comment: Cause for statement have : for (initialization; termination;
     increment) {
    statement(s)
}

Answer (score 1):

A for loop *can* have 3 arguments, but it's not required.

Usually goes like this

1. instruction
2. boolean
3. instruction

the first and the third one can be omitted safely.

So here is the first instruction slot used to initialize the iterator object.

The second instruction slot is used to see if there are new items in the iterator.

the third slot is not needed and thusly omitted.

This does the same as

```
Iterator<IBaseVO> itMachine = machinesSelected.iterator();
while (itMachine.hasNext()) {
            MachineVO mach = (MachineVO) itMachine.next();
            idsMachines.add(mach.getMchId());
        }
```

Comment: "the first and the third one can be omitted safely." All three can be omitted. `for (;;) {}` is legal.

Comment: I know it's legal, but it's not **safe** unless you bult in break;

Comment: the presence of the expression doesn't immediately make it safe, though. `for(;true;) {}` is just as "unsafe".